# Send Data to Database on row click in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I want to send a single string "clicked" in to my database if i click a single row in jqgrid table. The database already contains a column for the string but i don't know how to send the string from jqgrid. 
I can get the row and extract the primary key from the row with:

```
    var myDebugTrace = function (startingText, rowid) {
            var $this = $(this), p = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), rowData, col1,
            firstCol = (p.rownumbers ? 1 : 0) + (p.subGrid ? 1 : 0);

            rowData = $this.jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
            col1 = rowData[p.colModel[firstCol].name];
            ............
```

Than i just need a method in the code behind:
   InsertIntoDatabase(id,"checked")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to use a .ashx Handler and post data with ajax:

```
$.ajax({ url:"MyHandler.ashx" ...
```